# Duvida Select em Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho duas tabelas cidade e pessoas
Cidade tem as colunas

```
Id/idPrefeito/idVice/nome
```

E pessoas

```
Id/nome...
```

IdPrefeito e Vice são Foreign Key's de pessoas.id
Como eu trago no mesmo Select o nome da cidade, nome do Prefeito e nome do Vice??
Eu ja tentei:

```
SELECT cidade.nome, pessoas.nome, pessoas.nome AS Vice
FROM cidade, pessoas
WHERE cidade.idPrefeito = pessoas.id
AND cidade.idVice = pessoas.id
```

Porém este codigo não me retorna nada
Trocando "AND" por || ele me retorna 2 linhas onde na 1° Prefeito e vice tem o nome do Prefeito e na 2° Prefeito e vice tem o nome do Vice, Quase o que eu quero :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta fazer o join duas vezes, uma ligando `idPrefeito` e outra `idVice`, usando alias diferentes para cada uma:

```
SELECT cidade.nome, 
       ppref.nome as Prefeito, 
       pvice.nome AS Vice
FROM cidade
JOIN pessoa ppref ON cidade.idPrefeito = ppref.id
JOIN pessoa pvice ON cidade.idVice = pvice.id;
```

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb6720/4)

Comment: Funcionou muito obrigado amigo :)

Comment: legal, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta

Comment: Surgiu um novo problema quando idPrefeito e/ou idVice esta Null na tabela cidade, o código não retorna nada... Como faço pra ele retornar "null" quando for null e retornar tbm o nome do mesmo jeito que está ?

Comment: tente mudar o `join` para `left join`